# Passing variable through cbuffer vs. shader input in HLSL

Tags: shader, hlsl

Let's say I want to pass some kind of value to a pixel shader in HLSL. I can either make a cbuffer and pass the value directly to the pixel shader, or I can make a cbuffer in the vertex shader and pass the value into the pixel shader through the vertex shader output. What is the difference between these two methods and in which scenario is it better to use one or the other? Thanks.